# How to make a div draggable and contenteditable="true"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried over and over but i just can seem to get the text to be editable and also draggable, because when i apply .draggable() the contenteditable="true" becomes "false".

**Javascript**

```
$(".note").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css('height' , '100%');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
        <img src="images/close.png" height="30" width="30" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.note {
    width: 280px;
    height: 130px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 2;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Note;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("images/stickynote.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to make it so if you double click it will be editable, but single clicks will drag it.

```
$(".note").draggable()
  .click(function() {
    $(this).draggable( {disabled: false});

}).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
});
```

Add this to the close buttons `<img>` code will keep it in the top right of your container:

```
position: relative;
  top: -20px;
```

Comment: This works, however now the close button moves down while the text is being inputed. Is there a way to fix that or is it just normal.

Comment: Edited with a fix for the button as well.

Comment: i tried that but then when i erased the text the close button is to high. Is there a way to make the text go around the close button

Comment: Hmm, as far as doing that, your best bet may be to have your content editable div have a padding to the right and overlaying your close div, kind of like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/492/). This just shortens your text box and adds space to the right so the text can't go behind the close button.